# Catalog Search indexer process unknown error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1813

Tags: catalogsearch, reindex, indexer, magento2.2.0

```
    **Catalog** **Search indexer** process unknown error:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1813 Tablespace for table '`mydb`.`catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1_tmp`' exists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT., query was: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1_tmp` (
  `entity_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity ID' ,
  `attribute_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Attribute_id' ,
  `data_index` longtext NULL COMMENT 'Data index' ,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`entity_id`, `attribute_id`),
  FULLTEXT `FTI_FULLTEXT_DATA_INDEX` (`data_index`)
) COMMENT='catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1_tmp' ENGINE=innodb charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
```

When I try to do reindex I have this error. If I look into db for this table `catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1_tmp` it does not exists. But instead i sea that exist a table named `catalogsearch_fulltext_scope2`. I've tried to delete the `catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1_tmp` but there is no table in db...

The Magento is vs 2.2.0, PHP 7.0.25,

```
innodb_version          | 5.6.36-82.0                                          |
| protocol_version        | 10                                                   |
| slave_type_conversions  |                                                      |
| tls_version             | TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2                                      |
| version                 | 5.6.36-82.0                                          |
| version_comment         | Percona Server (GPL), Release 82.0, Revision 58e846a |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                                               |
| version_compile_os      | Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

a possible solution i found here [Error: Tablespace for table xxx exists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT](https://exceptionshub.com/error-tablespace-for-table-xxx-exists-please-discard-the-tablespace-before-import.html)

...so to solve this you must have permissions on server to delete manually the table space..., i didn't somebody else solve this, a server admin or so...